# Photo Gallary for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am new to iPhone developing. I want to create image gallery similar to safari browser history displayed. Can any one help how can it be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Coverflow animation in your project. It is same as safari History browser. Check out this [link](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel)
and this [link](http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/)